# JQuery: Using .last() with a created element in a .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, tabs, google-chrome-app

I'm currently making a tab structure similar to Google Chrome. I have recently made a "New Tab" button and function that adds a new tab. Right now my function only creates **one** tab. My code bases where the next tab elements will go in the HTML tree by using `$(".tab-clickable").last().after()`. The last `.tab-clickable` element represents the last part of the closest tab.

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/lectrician1/pen/baOxdO

I originally was using a `.click` event but switched to `.on` because I figured that there was an problem finding the the tab last created. So I ran a debugging test and apparently the `.on` wasn't the problem but the `$(".tab-clickable").last().after()` was. *But remember,* my code still creates a tab, only just one though. **I think the issue has to deal with finding the last `.tab-clickable` element that was just created in the first tab made.**

Comment: Ugh... there's so many things that could be improved in your code and logic... I'll try to put something together in an understandable answer

Comment: Post your code, please. It's impossible, for us, to understand your problem with the poor details you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is you are checking `tabAmount` only on page load. Need to check it each time you want to add another to get updated count

Move :

```
var tabAmount = $(".tab-clickable").length;
```

Into

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
   var tabAmount = $(".tab-clickable").length;
   // other code remains same
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post the relevant part of your code **in the question**  next time you ask, or edit your post.

You're determining the position of the new tab using the `tabAmount` variable which you initially set to 2. However, when you add a new tab, at no point do you increase this variable. Your code is producing new tabs, but they're just all being put in the same place over each other.

All you need to fix the problem is add `tabAmount++` to the end of the function (and decrement it if you remove a tag, or take it from the length each time)

Comment: By the way, I chuckled at "Coogle Grome"!